# MySQL compare by week

Tags: mysql, select

I have a select statement of which needs to base its `WHERE` on a timestamp but for all dates within that week beginning monday.

**The MySQL**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(unique_reference) AS unique_reference,  date(datetime) AS datetime
    FROM sales_tickets

    WHERE Date(datetime)='$datetime'
```

This is based on the fact that `$datetime` can be any date but the select statement needs to get all records from that week, example: if its the Monday 12th May 2014, it will fetch all results from that week, instead of the one day.

Currently, its fetching only one day of results.

I have no idea how to rectify this issue. Any advise would be awesome thanks.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function that takes a single argument.  It applies to the entire row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare using the [`WEEK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function :

```
WHERE WEEK(DATE(datetime)) = WEEK('$datetime')
```

If you have multiples years for entries, you can use instead the [`YEARWEEK` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek).

Edit for first day of week:
`WEEK` and `YEARWEEK` functions have both a second optional argument which tells when a week start. Try to consider mode 1 or 5.

```
Mode    First day of week   Range   Week 1 is the first week …
0   Sunday  0-53    with a Sunday in this year
1   Monday  0-53    with 4 or more days this year
2   Sunday  1-53    with a Sunday in this year
3   Monday  1-53    with 4 or more days this year
4   Sunday  0-53    with 4 or more days this year
5   Monday  0-53    with a Monday in this year
6   Sunday  1-53    with 4 or more days this year
7   Monday  1-53    with a Monday in this year
```

Comment: Can I issue a warning that this will not be able to use the indexes to search the columns, a between statement would be preferred if possible.

Comment: The OP wants weeks to start on Mondays, so beware to select the appropriate `mode` (the [default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_week_format) is usually Sunday-based).

Comment: No. this is not OP's expected answer.

Comment: This is close to what i need, but how would i make this work from the monday instead of sunday?

Comment: I've just edited my answer to add information of first day of a week.

Comment: Many thanks! Also, i have learned something today which makes me smile!

Answer (score 2):

A sargable solution would explicitly calculate the start and end points of your desired range:

```
WHERE datetime >= DATE('$datetime') + INTERVAL 0 - WEEKDAY('$datetime') DAY
  AND datetime <  DATE('$datetime') + INTERVAL 7 - WEEKDAY('$datetime') DAY
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method might be to have your WHERE statement check against a range of values, which you can calculate beforehand.
I'll assume you're using php.

So your SQL statement will be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(unique_reference) AS unique_reference,  date(datetime) AS datetime
FROM sales_tickets

WHERE (Date(datetime) > '$startDate')
   AND (Date(datetime) < '$endDate');
```

You'll first have to figure out what $startDate and $endDate are:

```
$endDate = strtotime('Monday', time()); // might need to adjust this depending on when your week starts 
$startDate = $endDate - 7*24*60*60; //one week before.
```

Be careful with converting times between unix timestamps and datetimes used in SQL, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try WEEK():

```
WHERE WEEK(datetime)=WEEK('$datetime')
```

Read more: [WEEK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)